# asp.net mvc: how to get Textbox value in controller in paging after URL changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that has a Textbox and a submit button. On submit it posts to a controller method i get the value of textbox only on submit method.In second paging i dont get the search textbox value:
here is my code:

View:

```
<div class="newinsightsSearch">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("NewsArticlesList", "NewsArticle" ))
    {
         @Html.TextBox("txtSearch","Search Insights", new { @class = "inputNewsSrch" })
        <input type="submit" id="btnSearch" class="btnSearch" />
    }
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult NewsArticlesList(string txtSearch)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    Currentpage = (Request.QueryString["pno"] != null) ? Request.QueryString["pno"] : "1";

    string Search = "";

    if (txtSearch != null)
    {
        Search = txtSearch;
    }
    else
    {
        Search = "";
    }

    Newsinsightmodel objnewsinsightlist = new Newsinsightmodel();

    if (Request.QueryString["Message"] != null)
    {
        Message = (Request.QueryString["Message"].ToString());
    }

    if (Request.QueryString["AgentID"] != null)
    {
        AuthorId = (Request.QueryString["AgentID"].ToString());
    }
    languageId = SessionHelper.GetCurrentLanguage();
    objnewsinsightlist.newsListCollection = GetNewsList(int.Parse(Currentpage), languageId, Search, AuthorId);
    objnewsinsightlist.TotalRecords = objnewsinsightlist.newsListCollection[0].TotalRecords;
    return View("NewsarticlesList", objnewsinsightlist);
}
```

In first page i get the texbox value on submit method but after clicking on second page textbox value is null in controller.

Comment: paging in on what show your complete view

Comment: Paging is through jquery plugin